# Find all paths that have a string in it

Tags: powershell, path, windows-10

Is it possible to make a script that finds all paths which include a string

I basically want the full path in which *\path\to\file* is valid..

How do you do this in windows and can you even do this??

Comment: Yes, all you got to do is to create a list of all the directories and filter that. This sounds a bit weird a task, so [what are you trying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version:

```
gci -path X:\start\here -r |?{ $_.FullName -match [regex]::escape("\path\to\file") }|%{$_.FullName}
```

And the verbose version:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\start\here -Recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.FullName -match [regex]::escape("\path\to\file")} |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

Sample output (with different path)

```
> gci -path q:\test -r |?{ $_.FullName -match [regex]::escape("\05\06\") }|%{$_.FullName}
Q:\test\2017\05\06\18-33.ps1
Q:\test\2017\05\06\19-46.cmd
Q:\test\2017\05\06\data.csv
Q:\test\2017\05\06\list.txt
Q:\test\2018\05\06\test
Q:\test\2018\05\06\Clipb2Var.cmd
Q:\test\2018\05\06\test\test.txt
```